# View test results for ALL builds of an artifact in Jenkins (not only recent)

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to display the test results for all builds (trend) in Jenkins? When I select an artifact the graph to the right just shows the last few results. I'm assuming it has to do with the timeframe in which those builds where made. Does Jenkins delete all test reports after a certain time?